# I found there a function "fopen",but how to use it?

Tags: arduino, arduino-due

I am amazing that arduino due has file operators.But where is my file?
I don't know what's the meaning of a file on a system without file system.

Comment: If you have an SD card plugged into your Arduino, then it does have a filesystem. Even if you don't have a physical filesystem (SD), you might have an in-memory one.

Answer (score 0):

You need the 3V compatible shield which has SD card slot. You can also implement the host USB stack and connect usb storage devices. You can also create your file system in the uC FLASH. The last two require vast knowledge of the hardware as I do not think that you will be able to find the arduino libraries for it.